# Find the vertical position of scrollbar without jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find the vertical position of the scrollbar a function similar to jQuery's scrollTop() but with no jQuery. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Isn't [element.scrollTop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop) sufficient?

Comment: just read the source of jQuery's scrollTop(): https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/offset.js

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Cross-browser solution:

```
var supportPageOffset = window.pageXOffset !== undefined;
var isCSS1Compat = ((document.compatMode || "") === "CSS1Compat");

var scrollLeft = supportPageOffset ? window.pageXOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft;
var scrollTop = supportPageOffset ? window.pageYOffset : isCSS1Compat ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop;
```

<sup>[**source**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.scrollY#Notes)</sup>

Comment: I think this should be accepted as an answer. The solution in the accepted answer is not cross-browser.

Comment: very little syntax correction: the comma at the end of the first row will generate an error - take care

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the scroll position exists within the DOM at:

```
window.scrollY;  //for vertical scroll.
```

How I found this:

> 1. In Chrome, right click and select Inspect Element.
> 2. Find and click the 'Show Console' button (lower-left)
> 3. In the console type window.scroll to see options.

-This is an exceptional workflow to solve a multitude of JavaScript questions.

**I see window.scrollTo(0) as an option to scroll to top.**

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,0)

Answer (score 8):

scrollX and scrollY.... scrollY is the equivalent of jquery `scrollTop()`