# How to make "Scroll further down" button on website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using wordpress' revolution slider that spans the home page. I want to put a scroll down button, so users are aware they can scroll. I want something like this one: https://exposure.so/

I tried putting a div on top of everything and a link that links to anchor link further down the page. It works, but I don't know how to make the div disappear when the user goes down, and reappear if they go back up. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: use javascript or jquery

Comment: Maybe show some code of what you have tried would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the scrollbar's handle position using javascript or jQuery.
If its towards the bottom of the page, hide the button, else show it.

To find scrollbar position : [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193453/find-the-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-without-jquery)