# Get the position of the scrollbar using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to show a tooltip like box as I scroll my webpage and I would like it to follow the scrollbar along the right side of the page.

I looked around and found something to attempt to accomplish that as shown below:

```
function returnPercentHeight(){
    var a = document.getElementById('rightPanel').scrollTop;
    var b = document.getElementById('rightPanel').scrollHeight - document.getElementById('rightPanel').clientHeight;
    return ((a/b) * 100);
}
```

I then append a % to the end and set the top margin of the tooltip to that returned value. This works pretty well (sort of) I have to adjust the `return((a/b) * x)` part (x) to make it follow the scrollbar based on the size of the browser window. Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do? (NOTE: I can only use javascript, no JQuery please.)

EDIT:

Only the div given an ID of 'RightPanel' is scrolling, I am not using the scrollbar on the browser, but a scrollbar on an inner div.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481350/retrieve-scrollbar-position-with-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193453/find-the-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-without-jquery

Comment: http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html

Comment: http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2010/5/9/getting-browsers-scroll-position-javascript/

Comment: http://dropshado.ws/post/4214189829/getting-and-setting-scroll-position

Comment: @IsmetAlkan please don't spam comments...

Comment: So the actual answer, after exploring other options, the final result became:

   `function returnPercentHeight(){
      var a = document.getElementById('rightPanel').scrollHeight;
      var b = document.getElementById('rightPanel').scrollTop + .5*document.getElementById('rightPanel').clientHeight;
      return ((b/a) * document.getElementById('rightPanel').clientHeight - 100);
    }`

where 100 is the height of the div that is scrolling with the scrollbar

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do so:

First:

is to use the fixed position as following;

```
Position: Fixed;
```

Second:

With jQuery;

```
$(function(){
   $(window).on('scroll', function() {
     var scrollPOS = $(document).scrollTop();
     $('.scroll').css({
        top: scrollPOS
     });
   }).scroll();
});
```

Third:

Same as the previous, only animated;

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
  $("#div").stop().animate({
     "marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop()) + "px", 
     "marginLeft":($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although IE doesn't support, this is the coolest I've seen:

```
// get
var x = window.scrollX,
    y = window.scrollY;

// set
window.scrollTo(1, 2);
```

Comment: I should mention that the whole page isn't scrolling, just one div on half the page.