# 100 percent height on body and html tags causes scroll issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have noticed some unexpected (by me anyway) behavior when the following css is used:

```
body, html{height:100%; overflow-x:hidden}
```

When the page has more height than the screen, vertical scrollbars appear as expected and the scroll event is detectable on the body element (rather than the window). The trouble is that the window.pageOffsetY property is no longer reflecting the scrolled position.  This is also affecting the pageY property of mouse events.

I have set up a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kevmc/n2sJB/ where you can see this in action.

Only when both body and html tags have the above styles does the problem arise. I know the simple answer is don't use those styles, but I am trying  to write a javascript component that I can use on many sites where I do not always have control over the stylesheet.

So my question is how can I measure the scroll position when the above styles are in place?

Comment: Does this still happen if you set the `margin` and `padding` to 0 on the `body`?

Comment: @steveax Yes, I'm afraid so. Just tried it with zero margins and padding on html, body and both - same results

Comment: In this scenario, you actually have two scrolling elements one inside the other. Are you sure this is actually a scenario that you encounter in real life?

Comment: @jcaron Not if I was writing the css :) however I have seen those styles in use where someone has been trying to implement a sticky footer.

Comment: `height: 100%` on both, yes, but not with the `overflow-x: hidden` or equivalent on both, surely?

Comment: @jcaron you'd hope not, but I've got no way of knowing what the level of skill (or the thought processes) of some of the people who have access to the css, and that style above is taken from one of our customers' sites.

Answer (score 1):

As you have set `height:100%` for both html and body elements, body become scrollable (not html/window as it was before), so you should check scroll offset of body element: `jQuery('body').scrollTop();` or try [solution without jQuery from Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193453/find-the-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-without-jquery)

Comment: I understand that the body element is scrolling, my trouble is in reliably measuring by how much.  

The body.scrollTop (and the jQuery version) value seems accurate in Firefox and IE11, but in chrome it still returns 0, I have added a console log to the fiddle to show these.

Unfortunately Engineer's solution will return the window.pageYOffset value, which is zero when the body not the window is scrolling.

Comment: @kevmc yep, my fault. Webkit-based browsers have a [bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows) with scroll offset calculation. The main problem is with `overflow` on HTML element that causes bug. I've prepared example on [jsFiddle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830080/jquery-scrolltop-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-safari-or-chrome-windows) to show CSS and how to calculate scroll offset.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `$('body').height($('body').height() + 1);`.