# Prevent a click on a link from jumping to top of page in Sennajs

Tags: javascript, senna.js

I'm a newbie to javascript, so please forgive if I ask things that are painfully obvious.

I am using [Sennajs](http://sennajs.com/) for my personal project. I have a issue like in [gallery example](http://sennajs.com/examples/gallery/static.html). When click a link, it makes the page jump to the top. I used to use this code from jquery to fix it. However it also prevents senna from working.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    // do something 
    return false;
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that you can use [`app.setUpdateScrollPosition(false)`](http://sennajs.com/api/App.html#setUpdateScrollPosition__anchor) to avoid jumping to the top of the page after every SennaJS navigation:

```
var app = new senna.App();
app.setUpdateScrollPosition(false);

// ...your code here...
```

---

## Old Solution (Not Recommended):

**Note:** this solution is unnecessarily overcomplicated since I wrote it before I knew about `app.setUpdateScrollPosition(false)`.

Instead of preventing SennaJS from executing, you could save the current scroll position before navigating and scroll to the correct position after navigating:

```
var app = new senna.App();

// ...your code here...

function getScrollTop() {

    // Taken from Engineer's answer:
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193453/find-the-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-without-jquery#11193613
    return (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset :
        (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
}

var scrollTop = getScrollTop();

app.on('beforeNavigate', function(event) {
    scrollTop = getScrollTop();
});

app.on('endNavigate', function(event) {
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop);
});
```

For more information about scroll positions and JavaScript, see [Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1113426/engineer)'s [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193453/find-the-vertical-position-of-scrollbar-without-jquery#11193613) and [MDN's `window.scrollTo()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo).

For more information about SennaJS Lifecycle Events, see [the SennaJS documentation](http://sennajs.com/docs#lifecycleevents)

<s>**Note:** this may be a bug in SennaJS, so I've created [a bug report (#184)](https://github.com/liferay/senna.js/issues/184).</s>

Answer (score 0):

You `return` before actually calling `preventDefault`. The following will work:

```
$(function(){
      $('a').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
      });
    });
```

Comment: Yes. However, I don't know how to make // do something with Sennajs. That's my issue. Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I suggest to just show more code so we can see the real issue

Comment: As I mentioned in my question. Their example gallery also has this problem. When you click on any image link it jumps to top of page. You can find it here http://sennajs.com/examples/gallery/static.html

Comment: What do you mean just to the top of the page. It seems that each time you click an image, a new page its loaded with that photo.

Comment: It's ajax. It do not loading completely new page. You can know this by opening browser inspection tool.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is because you `return` before doing anything.

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // do something 
    return false;
});
```

so, do something after you prevent the normal behaviour first.

Comment: Yes. However, I don't know how to make // do something with Sennajs. That's my issue. Please help.

Comment: Then don't make it a link...?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I must use a link, for SEO reason :(